# Find number of rows with values and latest date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have dataframe like that:

```
pk_id date
123   2020-01-01
223   2020-01-02
123   2020-01-03
224   2020-01-04
```

and I want to find `pk_id = 123` and `pk_id = 223` with their latest date and count the amount of such rows.

I have the following code

```
idx = plan_df.groupby('pk_id')['date'].idxmax()
df = df.loc[idx] 
df = df.loc[df['pk_id'] == 123]
```

that forms dataframe

```
pk_id   date
123    2020-01-03
223    2020-01-02
```

and now I find the number of rows

```
num = df.shape[0]
```

I believe it can be done in one line. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```py
out = df[df['pk_id'].isin([123, 223])].groupby('pk_id', as_index=False)['date'].max()
```

```
print(out)

   pk_id        date
0    123  2020-01-03
1    223  2020-01-02
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pandas query function

```
df.query("pk_id == 123 | pk_id == 223").groupby('pk_id', as_index=False)['date']
```